# Optimizing Divisor Sieve

Tags: python, optimization

I have two sieves that I wrote in python and would like help optimizing them if at all possible. The divisorSieve calculates the divisors of all numbers up to `n`. Each index of the list contains a list of its divisors. The numDivisorSieve just counts the number of divisors each index has but doesn't store the divisors themselves. These sieves work in a similar way as you would do a Sieve of Eratosthenes to calculate all prime numbers up to `n`.

*Note: `divs[i * j].append(i)` changed from `divs[i * j] += [i]` with speed increase thanks to a member over at stackoverflow. I updated the table below with the new times for divisorSieve. It was suggested to use this board instead so I look forward to your input.*

```
def divisorSieve(n):
    divs = [[1] for x in xrange(0, n + 1)]
    divs[0] = [0]
    for i in xrange(2, n + 1):
        for j in xrange(1, n / i + 1):
            divs[i * j].append(i) #changed from += [i] with speed increase.
    return divs

    def numDivisorSieve(n):
        divs = [1] * (n + 1)
        divs[0] = 0
        for i in xrange(2, n + 1):
            for j in xrange(1, n / i + 1):
                divs[i * j] += 1
        return divs

#Timer test for function
if __name__=='__main__':
    from timeit import Timer
    n = ...
    t1 = Timer(lambda: divisorSieve(n))
    print n, t1.timeit(number=1)
```

Results:

```
 -----n-----|--time(divSieve)--|--time(numDivSieve)--
    100,000 |  0.333831560615  |  0.187762331281
    200,000 |  0.71700566026   |  0.362314797537
    300,000 |  1.1643773714    |  0.55124339118
    400,000 |  1.63861821235   |  0.748340797412
    500,000 |  2.06917832929   |  0.959312993718
    600,000 |  2.52753840891   |  1.17777010636
    700,000 |  3.01465945139   |  1.38268800149
    800,000 |  3.49267338434   |  1.62560614543
    900,000 |  3.98145114138   |  1.83002270324
  1,000,000 |  4.4809342539    |  2.10247496423
  2,000,000 | 9.80035361075    |  4.59150618897
  3,000,000 | 15.465184114     |  7.24799900479
  4,000,000 | 21.2197508864    |  10.1484527586
  5,000,000 | 27.1910144928    |  12.7670585308
  6,000,000 | 33.6597508864    |  15.4226118057
  7,000,000 | 39.7509513591    |  18.2902677738
  8,000,000 | 46.5065447534    |  21.1247001928
  9,000,000 | 53.2574136966    |  23.8988925173
 10,000,000 | 60.0628718044    |  26.8588813211
 11,000,000 | 66.0121182435    |  29.4509693973
 12,000,000 |   MemoryError    |  32.3228102258

 20,000,000 |   MemoryError    |  56.2527237669
 30,000,000 |   MemoryError    |  86.8917332214
 40,000,000 |   MemoryError    |  118.457179822
 50,000,000 |   MemoryError    |  149.526622815
 60,000,000 |   MemoryError    |  181.627320396
 70,000,000 |   MemoryError    |  214.17467749
 80,000,000 |   MemoryError    |  246.23677614
 90,000,000 |   MemoryError    |  279.53308422
100,000,000 |   MemoryError    |  314.813166014
```

Results are pretty good and I'm happy I was able to get it this far, but I'm looking to get it even faster. If at all possible, I'd like to get ***100,000,000*** at a reasonable speed with the divisorSieve. Although this also brings into the issue that anything over ***12,000,000+*** throws a `MemoryError` at `divs = [[1] for x in xrange(0, n + 1)]`) in divisorSieve. numDivisorSieve does allow the full ***100,000,000*** to run. If you could also help get past the memory error, that would be great.

I've tried replacing numDivisorSieve's `divs = [1] * (n + 1)` with both `divs = array.array('i', [1] * (n + 1))` and `divs = numpy.ones((n + 1), dtype='int')` but both resulted in a loss of speed (slight difference for array, much larger difference for numpy). I expect that since numDivisorSieve had a loss in efficiency, then so would divisorSieve. Of course there's always the chance I'm using one or both of these incorrectly since I'm not used to either of them.

I would appreciate any help you can give me. I hope I have provided enough details. Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing with the result?

Comment: If storing only prime factors counts as 'optimization', we can do ~3-4 times faster.

Comment: Have you tested the application using Python 64bit?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about Python 64bit. It's looking like it solves the memory issues. Will update once I've run all the tests

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xrange`'s third param to do the stepping for you to shave off a little bit of time (not huge).

Changing:

```
for j in xrange(1, n / i + 1):
    divs[i * j].append(i)
```

To:

```
for j in xrange(i, n + 1, i):
    divs[j].append(i)
```

For `n=100000`, I go from `0.522774934769` to `0.47496509552`.  This difference is bigger when made to `numDivisorSieve`, but as I understand, you're looking for speedups in `divisorSieve`

Comment: This was a great optimization! for `n = 10,000,000` divisorSieve's time is down to _**9.56704298066**_ and for `n = 100,000,000` numDivisorSieve's time is down to _**67.1441108416**_ which are both great optimizations.

Comment: Wow... that's better than I expected!  Glad I could help.

Comment: Well...apparently the reason it did so well is I had the range messed up. So while it's still an improvement, it's not quite as good as I thought. Doesn't make me appreciate your help any less, just makes me feel a little stupid. Guess that's what I get for not testing the output well enough. Will update the original post when I get a chance to recompute all the results

Comment: @JeremyK That's fine.  At least I know I'm not crazy now.  :)

Comment: @JeremyK I was commenting on your OP about the erratic range before reading this. You should update the post - atleast change the code and say that the results are incorrect for now.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: `map(lambda s: s.append(i) , [divs[ind] for ind in xrange(i, n + 1, i)])`
Seems to be <del>~0.2% faster</del> **~2 times slower** than Adam Wagner's (for `n=1000000`)

The infamous 'test the unit test' problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something incorrectly, but when I put this in there I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not xrange`

Comment: **~2 times slower** Must be due to function call overhead for calling the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

The following offers a very very small improvement to `divisorSieve` and a good improvement to `numdivisorSieve`. But the factors will not be sorted inside each list. For example the factors list of  of 16 will be [4, 2, 8, 1, 16].

```
def divisorSieve(n):
    divs = [[] for j in xrange(n + 1)]
    nsqrt = int(sqrt(n))
    for i in xrange(1, nsqrt + 1):
        divs[i*i].append(i)
        for j in xrange(i, i*i, i):
            divs[j].append(j/i) #If j/i is replaced by i, a good improvement is seen. Of course, that would be wrong.
            divs[j].append(i)
    for i in xrange(i+1, n+1):
        for j in xrange(i, n+1, i):
            divs[j].append(j/i)
            divs[j].append(i)
    return divs

def numdivisorSieve(n):
    divs = [1] * (n + 1)
    divs[0] = 0
    nsqrt = int(sqrt(n))
    for i in xrange(2, nsqrt + 1):
        divs[i*i] += 1
        for j in xrange(i, i*i, i):
            divs[j] += 2
    for i in xrange(i+1, n+1):
        for j in xrange(i, n+1, i):
            divs[j] += 2
    return divs
```

Unfortunately, modifying this definition to create two lists divsmall ([4,2,1]) and divlarge ([8,16]) and in the end doing `divsmall[j].reverse(); divsmall[j].extend(divlarge[j]); return divsmall` makes it slightly slower than the original.

Also, I think it makes more sense for `divs[0]` to be `[]` instead of `[0]`